# Cron is repeating every minute

Tags: linux, cron

This is how it looks

```
* * 10 * * php sendmail.sh
```

I want this to send mail on the 10th of every month.

Comment: i like write-only users... :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Then you need to set a time. * means repeat minute/hour/day/whatver. What you want is

```
1 0 10 * * php sendmail.sh
```

Comment: Ah I somehow missed that

Answer (score 14):

Here is a nice reminder : 
[image]
<sub>(source: [joshhighland.com](http://joshhighland.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/cron.png))</sub>

Comment: As long as it's /etc/crontab (or /etc/cron.d), user crontabs have no username field.